# SSH operation timed out while connecting to ubuntu

Tags: ssh, ufw

I have a Ubuntu server in which Nginx is configured as a reverse proxy to my web application. After configuring UFW rules for Nginx I am unable to do ssh with my box. I suspected this could be the issue with firewall rules and allowed SSH and port 22. I have rebooted the server. But none of them worked.

[image]

Apologies for adding the pictures as I am unable to copy the firewall rules from the console.

I am getting the following message when i try to ssh the host

ssh: connect to host 131.90.210.220 port 22: Operation timed out

I tried restarting the server. It did not help in solving this issue.

Comment: A timeout usually points toward a firewall problem. A reboot seldom fixes a firewall problem. The firewall can be on your server, on your client, or anywhere inbetween.

Comment: I tried rebooting the server. But it did not work.

Comment: Certainly the port is blocked on your network either for incoming or outgoing.